# Чи можна вживати слово "далекобійник"?

Tags: значення-слів, відповідник

"Далекобійник" або "фурник" - це просторічна назва професії водіїв великовантажних автомобілів. Жодних з цих слів немає в СУМі, а тому у мене виникло питання чи можна їх вживати в офіційній лексиці?

А якщо "ні", то як краще замінити це слово, бо я ще чув наступні варіанти:

Водій великовантажного автомобіля

Водій вантажного авто

**Водій-міжнародник**

З цих всіх, на мою думку, найкращим є "водій-міжнародник", адже "далекобійники" - це не просто водії вантажних автомобілей, вони також здійснюють перевезення на валикі відстані. Однак, я не впевнений, що "[водій-міжнародник](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&client=firefox-b-d&ei=AZOvXJ2PNcvMrgScuamwCw&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjdk53n4MjhAhVLposKHZxcCrYQ8NMDCIUB&biw=1366&bih=654)" також не є просторічною назвою.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевірила, який можливий переклад російського слова "дальнобойщик"

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> **Дальнобойщик**, разг. – фу́рник, (рус.) **далекобі́йник**, дальнобійник
>
> *У кількох метрах від нього курила проститутка: видно, недавно відправила якогось дальнобійника та чекає на наступного (О.Форостина).
>   Страх стис їй легені, як одноразову серветку в важкому кулаці стискає
>   далекобійник (Катерина Бабкіна).*

В СУМ-20 вже є слово "далекобійник" в означенні, яке Вас цікавить. Проте слово з позначкою розмовне, що обмежує вживання в діловому мовленні.

> ***[Далекобійник](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=205122&page=705),*** розм. Водій вантажівки, перев. автотрейлера, що
>   перевозить вантажі на великі відстані (на сотні, тисячі кілометрів).

Краще вживати новостворене слово "водій-міжнародник", обидва слова в СУМ без будь-яких позначок

> [Водій](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15459&page=511) Особа, яка керує транспортним засобом і отримує платню за
>   перевезення кого-, чого-небудь. [Міжнародник](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=51279&page=1627)  Фахівець із питань
>   міжнародної політики, міжнародного права.